# Full screen windows media player

Tags: vb.net, video

I've read quite a few of the articles/answers on playing videos in full screen on Windows Media Player, but I'm not having much success.  I'm using Visual Basic Express 2010 to play videos in some very simple applications.  Here's what hasn't worked.

In the VB code for the event that starts the video:

```
Private Sub picVideoStart_Click(sender As System.Object, 
         e As System.EventArgs) Handles picVideoStart.Click
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Videos\Bear8.mp4"
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.autoStart = True
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.mute = True
    picVideoStart.Visible = False

    If AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying Then
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I've also tried setting the Full Screen property to True in the Visual Basic Express properties window.

Here is what has worked.  If I right-click on the AxWindowsMediaPlayer1 in design mode, I get a menu and then select "Properties."  If I put a checkmark in the box for "Play Full Screen" the video will play in Full Screen - but only one time.  If the user of the application plays the video again, the video reverts to a partial screen.

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
   'Can only set the full screen mode when the video is playing
   Do While AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState <> WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying
        Application.DoEvents()
   Loop
   AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = My.Settings.AlbumPlayVideoFullScreen
```